# Networked machine 'bypasses' password protection on Win7 shares

Tags: networking, password, share

I've just encountered an odd problem that is the exact opposite of what you'd expect:  One of three machines on a local network somehow remembers passwords for the other machines, despite reboots and attempts to flush cache.

The machines are all running Win7.  Password protection is set for shared drives.  When rebooted, the first two machines require that the password for the shares be entered.  Machine 3 somehow remembers the passwords through reboots of any of the machines.

It's difficult to figure a coherent google search phrase for this, especially in that it turns up the opposite problem (machines that do -not- remember passwords).  I did find mention of "net use * /delete" as a possible reset, but that does not work.  In fact, "net use" says "there are no entries in the list."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Go to control panel -> user accounts -> manage user accounts.  Click the advanced tab on top of that window.  There should be a button there that says "manage passwords".  This should allow you to delete any previously saved credentials in windows 7.

[image: The screenshot below shows what I see on a win7 enterprise box]

If you're using win10 the "manage credentials" will work for you, but you have to make sure that you're managing "windows credentials" and not "web credentials".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jason.  But there is no link to 'manage user accounts' on my Win7 machines.  Does this relate to Win10?

Comment: There are links to 'manage your credentials' and 'Configure advanced profile properties', neither of which have an 'advanced' tab.  Under 'configure advanced...' there are profiles listed, but none that would relate to the machines in question.  There were two 'account unknown' profiles that I deleted with no apparent effect. I don't see other options.  The odd thing is that I have to specifically enter passwords on the other two machines. I didn't think it was possible to simply bypass that step once the passwords were set...?!